# How to switch git branches in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-branch

I have GitHub repository with multiple branches, and I want to commit and push changes to a specific branch, how can I switch from "master*" branch to another branch?

I tried to switch by clicking the branch name in the left bottom side of the screen and it didn't switch.

Comment: Why don't you use console? `git checkbout branchname`? CTRL+` will open the terminal in VSCode

Comment: it doesn't recognize them

Comment: if using the terminal way does not work, that is how do it, you are not in a git repo, or the repo has no branches, list the branches with `git branch`

Comment: it has branches but the terminal doesn't recognize them, and if i try the source control way i can see them but even if click on any branch it doesn't switch

Answer (score 0):

1. Access the "Source Control" tab on the left side of VSCode
2. Click on the "three small dots" next to the refresh button
3. Click on the "Checkout to..." option
4. Choose the branch you want to switch to

You can also try this:
you do `git branch branch_name` then `git checkout branch_name`

Comment: I tried and it didn't work

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
// it will create new branch and switch to that branch
git checkout -b branch-name

// it will directly switch to previously created branch
git checkout branch-name
```

Answer (score 0):

for switching between the branches. If you have already more than one branch.

```
git switch <branch-name> //name of the branch where you want to switch
```

or,

```
git checkout <branch-name>
```

for creating the branch you can use

```
git branch <branch-name> //Name of the branch you want to create
```

and for creating and switching to that branch simuntaneously.

```
git switch -c <branch-name>
```