# Is there a setting to reactivate "Create new branch" when switching branches?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branch, settings

In previous versions of vscode it was possible to switch branches and instantly creating a new, if it does not exists. That doesn't work anymore because the "Create new Branch" DropDown disappears.

What I mean:

Open the branch in the lower left corner, the "Select branch or tag to checkout" window appears:

[select a branch or tag to checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqBAw.png)

The option "Create new branch" stayed there even when typing in a branch, that does not exist.

In the current version it now disappears:
[new Branch name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWDSh.png)

I used this to create new branches on-the-fly, if there is no branch with this name already existing.
Is there an option to re-enable this? It's really annoying to first search for existing branches and then deleting everything, activating "Create" and then retyping everything.

We are working based on work item IDs, so there is often the case that a branch either exists or not exists, depending on if there was already some work involved.

I searched for a setting, but couldn't find one.

Comment: check this please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74632926/how-to-switch-git-branches-in-vscode

Comment: I saw this, but this is not my problem. Switching branches works fine, but creating a new one from the box does not work.

Yes, typing in the git command would work, but is not the preferred way.

Comment: can you provide the VS version you are working with ? also (if the normal cmd is not preferied try working with gitbash )

Comment: Version: 1.86.2